# How to resolve React Native Android Axios Network Error?

Tags: android, reactjs, axios

I was using Axios post request to do an API call. It was working fine with iOS but for Android, it was shown **Network Error 400**.

When I try encoded URL with `encodeURIComponent` like the following and API was successful with status 200.

```
return await axios.post(encodeURIComponent(url),JSON.stringify(data), config)
.then(({ data }) => {
  return { success: 1, data };
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('error', error)
  return { success: 0, error: error.message };
});
```

Comment: Can you please share a little more details, on which android version do you get this error and do the api server have SSL installed i.e. does your api url starts with https or http ?

Comment: Since, there little details concerning the problem. I will say make sure the `Content-Type` header is set. Iv

Answer (score 0):

Since, there little details concerning the problem. I will say make sure the `Content-Type` header is set. It's always necessary on android.